# unable to launch localhost:3000 on mac with docker set up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, osx-yosemite

I am trying to set up another dockerized node app . I already have one which is up and running app and working as expected. But second app on start fails to launch http://localhost:3000 Please note, first app is properly shut down when I am working on second app.

Following is my docker-composer.yml

```
    version: '3.0'

services:
  web:
    image: node:boron
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'dev'
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:xxxx@db:5432/myapp
    depends_on:
      - db 
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    tty: true

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xxxxx"

$ docker-compose run --service-ports web 
$cd app
$npm run web
```

run the app as expected

docker ps -a shows the mapping too 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp

but when I launch http://localhost:3000/api/message

It loads page with message Site can't be launched ...

```
$docker ps
b9b90610051a        node:boron          "/bin/bash"              6 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   app_web_2
14739cf56f24        postgres:9.6.3      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 hours ago         Up 6 hours          5432/tcp                 app_db_1


package.json
{
  "name": “my app”,
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/bin/www/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/bin/www/index.js",
    "build": "tic -p .",
    "dev": "ts-watch --onSuccess \"node ./dist/bin/www/index.js\""
  },
```

> index.ts file - http listening code

```
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 3000);
const env = Environment.for(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
console.log('Starting server...'+port)
function startServer(env : Environment) {

  const app = new App(env).express;
  app.set('port', port);

  const server = http.createServer(app);
  server.on('error', onError);

  server.on('listening', function() {
    let addr = server.address();
    let bind = (typeof addr === 'string') ? `pipe ${addr}` : `port ${addr.port}`;
    console.log(`Listening on ${bind}`);
  });  
}
```

Comment: Is it connection refused or an HTTP error? What does the logs for that service show? Which is the command of that image?

Comment: An IP address of all zeros means this network any host on this network; the local host address is 127.0.0.1

Comment: what does `docker ps` give (without `-a` flag)?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu how can I check service log for container

Comment: @tgallacher updated the question please check

Comment: @MatthewLagerwey I know , I am using docker container

Comment: Are you sure `npm run dev` is not listening (inside the container) to localhost only?

Comment: @whites11 it start the server and when i get a url via postman it is not reaching to the server as well...usually it showing  GET request  in console.log...

Comment: Could you share your package.json's web script definition?

Comment: @whites11 please check....I have removed the dependencies..let me know if those are needed

Comment: Ok, now also the `./dist/bin/www/index.js` file if possible. Just need the part that starts the http listening socket.

Comment: @user269867 `docker-compose logs web` will show *web* service logs.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu show "Attaching to " that's it

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing to define the *command* of *web* service on the docker-compose.yml:

```
...
entrypoint: /bin/bash 
tty: true 
command: "npm start"
...
```

Have in mind that, even tough **web** will be started when **db** is up, is not guaranteed that the database is ready when you start your app.
[docker-cmpose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) suggests to use
**wait-for-it**, **dockerize**, or sh-compatible **wait-for** to control startup order.

You could also define a [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) (or [Dockerfile healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck)) to check whether the database is available or not.

Comment: in package.json I have   "start": "node dist/bin/www/index.js",

Comment: I mean in to add it in docker-compose.yml

Comment: I have already one docker containerized app , I am trying to spin up the other one ....is it possible to have multiple docker container running node app  separately .

Comment: Not on the same port (on the host)

Comment: @tgallacher if I give different ports then I can run different node js app on same host ? If you have any reference it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Looking over your `compose` file again, you need to ensure your entry node script is calling the bootup function, `startServer` -- you define it but don't call it. You should also ensure that the web service is invoking your Nodejs script. For example:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web:
    image: node:boron
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'dev'
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:xxxx@db:5432/myapp
    depends_on:
      - db 
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
    command: ["node", "dist/index.js"]
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xxxxx"
```

As you are using Typescript, you'll need to build your JS, which I assume will be in a `dist` folder. Also, if your app needs to wait for the `db` to be up and running, you can use the example `wait-for-postgres.sh` script discussed here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/; then update your `entrypoint` accordingly.

As for running multiple nodejs apps on the same host, you can do this as long as they each bind to a separate port on the host. So you can duplicate your `web` service and update the app entrypoint (`dist/index.js` above) and the Docker host port (i.e. your computer -- the internal node app can still listen on 3000). For example,

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web1:
    image: node:boron
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'dev'
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:xxxx@db:5432/myapp
    depends_on:
      - db 
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
    command: ["node", "dist/index1.js"]
  web2:
    image: node:boron
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'dev'
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:xxxx@db:5432/myapp
    depends_on:
      - db 
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
    command: ["node", "dist/Index2.js"]
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "xxxxx"
```

Although, if you need multiple instances of the same web service for scaling or load management, then you should look into horizontal container scaling solution, such as [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io).

Hope that helps.